# React useState, setState and {state} in return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I come across the rendering issue with React State.
The problem is that `{state}` in return get value one beat late.
But the console log in `handleChange` shows right value.
If the previous value of state is 9, current value of state value is 10 then the `console.log({state})` in `handleChange` shows 10 and the `<span>{state}<span>` in return shows 9.
It looks different from other state async problem.
I can't understand why this happened.

```
const [findText, setFindText] = useState("");
const [findCount, setFindCount] = useState(0);
```

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    let str = e.target.value;
    setFindText(str);

    let cnt = 0;
    doxDocument.map((docx) => {
      cnt += docx.src.split(findText).length - 1;
    });
    setFindCount(cnt);
    console.log({findCount})
};
```

```
return( 
<div>
  <input
    type="text"
    value={findText}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
  <span>{findCount} found <span>
</div>
);
```

Comment: Can you share what is there in `doxDocument`

Comment: Not related to your problem but this looks like a complete mis-use of `filter()`. I'd use `reduce()` to perform a _sum_ operation

Comment: yes, the filter() is trace of other function. Thanks to point out that

Comment: And `doxDocument` is arrary of sentneces ex) ['blablabla', 'bla2blalba2', ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems...

1. `findText` will not have been updated to the new value when you use it in `split()`. Either use `str` instead or calculate `findCount` in a [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) or [effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook with a dependency on `findText`.
2. You're completely misusing `filter()`. Use `reduce()` to calculate a computed sum

```jsx
  const [findText, setFindText] = useState("");
  const findCount = useMemo(
    () =>
      findText
        ? doxDocument.reduce(
            (sum, { src }) => sum + src.split(findText).length - 1,
            0
          )
        : 0,
    [findText, doxDocument] // may not need doxDocument
  );

  return (
    <div id="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={findText}
        onChange={(e) => setFindText(e.target.value)}
      />
      <span>{findCount} found</span>
    </div>
  );
```

[image: Edit autumn-river-jslqtt]

Comment: Thanks. reduce and useMemo works well !!
And It do not need doxDocument to make right value

Comment: @Shanha_Kim right. `doxDocument` would only be required in the dependencies list if it was managed by React state

Comment: One more question with original code, in `handleChange` when I check the findText, findCount in console.log, they show right value. But `{findCount}` in return don't. Why is this happened?

Comment: @Shanha_Kim your original code was working with the previous value of `findText` because it wasn't waiting for it to update which is why it looked like `findCount` wasn't updating. I strongly suggest avoiding `console.log()` for any debugging and stick with what you actually see rendered

Comment: I understand what you said a little bit. Thank you so much